# Jquery - jqtransform buttons looking weird in IE?

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, jqtransform

for some reason my buttons using `jqtransform` are looking really weird when viewed in IE.

They are fine when viewed in chrome, opera,firefox or safari.

Basically, a portion of the left, bottom part of the button is cutoff.  Anybody else having this problem?

Here's a picture:

[image]

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer, and can you provide code/demo?

Comment: I checked with IE6/7/8 .Having same problem with all

Comment: It's difficult to best assist without seeing a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by adding this line in the JSP,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: If a doctype is the issue, use the shorter standards based one: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.